# use <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script> and action="php.php" in the same HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

G'day,

I have this HTML page with the following - 
1. A form with textboxes in it so the user can enter some information like, username and password. 
2. Script tag type javascript with the source file "mlogin.js" specified at the top to validate the user input and generate alert messages, if required.
 
3. The form has action="mlogin.php" which takes the information from the HTML page and checks it aganist the login information and if the information is correct, redirect the user to another page.
4. Submit button at the end of the form. 
- If I set the type to "button", mlogin.js works perfectly fine BUT the user is not redirected.
- If I set the type to "Submit", and if the user misses out a textfield, "mlogin.js" generates an alert and when I click OK, I'm redirected to the other page.

What I want to happen - 
If the user misses out a textfield, I want the java script to generate an alert AND the page to stay there. Once all the textfields are filled and the user hits Submit, go to .php and check the information and if it's correct, redirect the user.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, this is an example of js validation I use:

```
//all forms must be filled
    var a=document.forms["usersignupform"]["username"].value;
    var b=document.forms["usersignupform"]["pass"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="" || b==null || b=="")
    {
        alert("Fill in all required forms.");
        return false;
    }
```

Though I'm not sure that's exactly what you're asking. What exactly is your problem?

I'll give you an example how I do it, and hopefully that'll clear up your confusion.

I use 2 files for form validation, to make them easier to navigate(you can use only one). One is called signup.php and one is called signupphpjs.php. In signup.php I have a line that includes all of the code from signupphpjs.php at the top(above the head, inside php tags): `include signupphpjs.php` then I have the form validation.

`Action=''`, because the script is "included" in signup.php and onsubmit='return javascriptfunction()', which is in the javascript portion at the bottom of signupphpjs.php.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: I basically have 3 file - HTML, JS and PHP. I want the HTML to take the user input, JS to validate it and PHP to check the input from HTML aganist the correct information and if it's correct, redirect the user to another page.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you're saying but I'm supposed to use form in HTML file.

Comment: Check my update and:
`<script src="javasciptcode.js"></script>` should be in the head of the html, and then use the `onsubmit` form attribute as noted, and use an include 'phpfile.php' for that. Though, as I stated in my answer you could just put the javascript in your php validation file, at the bottom with `<script>` tags.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why you can't just rename the .html file to a .php file, but I'll look into it.

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm This page includes a way to include php in .html files with .htaccess, but I would recommend just changing the html file to a php file, unless there is some definite reason you can't do that.

Comment: My exact thoughts. My teachers says we need to use HTML and hence, the confusion.

Comment: You would still be using html, just in a php file. Teachers can be a pain... I learned programming on my own, I've never had a good programming teacher.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. The pdf specifically says "Design an HTML page" :(